# Difference Between $block and $this with Example in magento 2.4.4?

Tags: blocks, magento2.4.4

I want to know what is the main difference between $block and $this with example. And also wants to know what are the classes of $this and $block.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Difference - Nothing**

Regardless of what object in template you use (`$block` or `$this`) always will be called method from `$block`.

Magic happens in `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::__call()`.

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array([$this->_currentBlock, $method], $args);
}
```

So `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php` is only proxy between template and `$block`, hence `$block` usage is preferred because of direct call.

Additionaly check `\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php::render()` to understand how `$block` is available in template.

**2.what are the classes of $this and $block**

It contains a reference to an instance of a template’s block type.

You can use all methods of template's block.